# How to calculate the percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
Date     id   salary

01/2012  001   1500
01/2011  001   750
01/2010  001   500
```

from the table1, i want to make a percentage for the datewise

Expected output

```
Date    id  salary percentage

01/2012 001 1500   100%
01/2011 001 750    50% 
01/2010 001 500    0%
```

Condition

```
01/2010 salary is 500, then 01/2011 salary is 750, so 50 percentage increased from 01/2010 salary
01/2011 salary is 750, then 01/2012 salary is 1500, so 100 percentage increase from 02/2011 salary
```

How to make a query for calculating the percentage.

Need query help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @richardtallent said, there are two parts: (1) Finding the previous salary , and (2) calculating the percentage. But since you are using sqlserver 2k CTEs are not supported. I use to do the following way:

For (2) I usually have two functions created: percentage and increment:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[percentage] (@a float(53), @b float(53))
RETURNS float(53)
BEGIN
  RETURN (CASE WHEN COALESCE(@b,0)=0 THEN NULL ELSE @a/@b END)*100.
END
```

And

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[increment] (@a float(53), @b float(53))
RETURNS float(53)
BEGIN
  RETURN dbo.percentage(@a,@b)-100.
END
```

For (1) you can use a subselect and then you have it.

```
SELECT S.date, S.id, S.salary, 
       dbo.increment((SELECT TOP 1 salary 
                      FROM table1 
                      WHERE id=S.id AND date<S.date 
                      ORDER BY date DESC),
                     salary) AS percentage
FROM table1 S
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question: (1) Finding the previous salary for any given salary, and (2) calculating the percentage.

The first part:

```
WITH salarieswithprevious AS (
   SELECT date, id, salary, 
      COALESCE(SELECT salary FROM table t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t1.date > t2.date
         AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM table t3 WHERE t3.id=t1.id 
            AND t3.date > t2.date AND t3.date < t1.date), salary) AS previoussalary
   FROM
      table t1
   )
```

This matches each salary with the salary most recent before it. It coalesces the value with the current salary if there is no previous salary, which means the "raise" for that year will be 0%.

The second part:

```
SELECT date, id, salary, 
   ( (salary - previoussalary) / previoussalary * 100 ) AS PctIncrease
FROM
   salarieswithprevious
```

This does the easy part, simple percentage math.

Comment: Can't do this with SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 0):

In my View Better you go for cursors,first create the column by altering the table and fetch the last row via cursor in the table

```
declare @date datetime,@id int,@salary numeric,@percentage decimal(5,2)
declare SalCursor cursor static
  FOR SELECT date,id,Salary FROM table1
  open SalCursor 
  fetch last FROM SalCursor into @date,@id,@salary
  while @@fetch_status<>-1
  begin
    --code to calculate  percentage goes here
  Update table1 set percentage=@percentage where id=@id
  end
```

Hope it give you some rough idea...
All the best..

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a CTE by doing something like:

```
WITH CTETable (Row, Date, id, salary) AS
(
    SELECT Row_Number() over (order by id,Date) AS Row , 
    Date,
         id, 
    salary
    FROM sourceTable
) 
SELECT 
    T1.Row, 
    T1.Date,
         T1.id
    T1.salary, 
    CASE 
                  -- First row in table, return 0 for Pct
        WHEN T1.Row = 1 THEN 0
                  -- Switching ids, return 0 for Pct
                  WHEN T1.id <> (SELECT T2.id FROM CTETable AS T2
                                 WHERE T2.Row = T1.Row - 1) THEN 0
                  -- else subtract the prior row's salary from the current row
                  -- and divide by the prior row's salary
        ELSE (T1.salary - (SELECT T2.salary FROM CTETable AS T2 
                WHERE T2.Row = T1.Row - 1) * 1.0)  /
             ((SELECT T3.salary FROM CTETable AS T3 
              WHERE T3.Row = T1.Row - 1) * 1.0)
    END * 100 AS Pct
FROM CTETable AS T1
```

Comment: can't use this in sql-server 2000

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table #tr(dates datetime,id int,salary int)
insert into #tr values('01/01/2012' , 001 ,  1500)
insert into #tr values('01/01/2011'  ,001,   750)
insert into #tr values('01/01/2010' , 001 ,  500);

WITH tablename as
(

SELECT ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION by t1.dates  order by t1.dates)rno, T1.*,isnull((cast((T1.salary - isnull(T2.salary,T1.salary))as decimal(16,3))/T2.salary),0)*100 as 'Percentage'  FROM #tr T1
left JOIN #tr T2 on T1.id = T2.ID and T1.dates >T2.dates 

)  

SELECT * FROM tablename where rno = 1    

drop table #tr
```

Comment: can't use row_number in sql-server 2000

Comment: then try with hash tables add an extra field

Comment: I heard of tables, temporary tables and table variables. But i have never heard about hash tables in MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Its more dynamic:

```
create table #tr(dates datetime,id int,salary int)
insert into #tr values('01/01/2012' , 001 ,  1500)
insert into #tr values('01/01/2011'  ,001,   750)
insert into #tr values('01/01/2010' , 001 ,  500)
insert into #tr values('01/01/2011'  ,002,   750)
insert into #tr values('01/01/2010' , 002 ,  500)

with T as (
select ID, dates incDate, Salary, ROW_NUMBER() over( partition by id order by id, Dates) AS rn from #tr)
select T.id,T1.salary ,T.incdate,(T1.Salary-T.salary)*100/T.Salary as PercHike  from T join T T1 on T.id=T1.id and T.rn=(T1.rn-1)
UNION
select id,min(Salary) as Salary ,min(dates) as Incdate , 0 as PercHike from #tr group by Id 
ORDER BY ID , incDate

drop table #tr
```

In scenario where Id are different, earlier suggested solution doest perform.

Comment: can't use row_number in sql-server 2000